# python argparse library does not read arguments

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I am trying to create a cli.

I would like to eventually have those functionalists:

- `myProgram create id name file`
- `myProgram delete id`
- `myProgram update id file`

This is what I have so far.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('mode')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
parser_delete = subparsers.add_parser('delete')
parser_delete.add_argument('id')
print parser.parse_args()
```

However when I put such command,

```
myProgram deelte 123
```

I get

```
Namespace<id='123', mode='mode'>
```

Note that mode is NOT 'delete'

Instead I have to put in

```
myProgram delete delete 123
```

to get

```
Namespace<id='123', mode='delete'>
```

I wonder why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `dest` keyword to the `parser.add_subparsers()` call, and leave out the `mode` argument:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='mode')
```

Now the subparser name is included as `mode`:

```
$ cat test.py 
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='mode')
parser_delete = subparsers.add_parser('delete')
parser_delete.add_argument('id')
print parser.parse_args()

$ python test.py delete 123
Namespace(id='123', mode='delete')
```

Do read the [sub-commands documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) more carefully though; there are better options, including associating a function to call with each sub-parser, so that you don't have to explicitly track the name of the subparser like this.

Answer (score 0):

You've added an argument, and a subparser, and an argument for that subparser. That's three arguments.

If you wanted the "mode" to be the thing that selects the subparser, you don't need that; it's what happens automatically. Remove the `add_argument('mode')` and you can run it as `myProgram delete 123` just fine.

If you want to get the value of the subparser chosen as the `mode` value in the namespace, just add `dest='mode'` to the `add_subparsers` call.

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to read the arguments you enter in the command line location wise, use python's `sys.argv`

when you call script `args.py` like so:

```
$ args.py delete 123
```

args.py should look like:

```
import sys

print sys.argv[1] # Prints delete
print sys.argv[2] # Prints 123
```

Comment: This is what `argparse` handles *for* you.

Comment: `argparse` is usually used when you need flags/switches/arguments, is it necessary to use `argparse` if OP is not going to use it's main features?

Comment: The OP is trying to solve one specific problem *with `argparse`*. What makes you think the full application won't use argparse features?

Comment: OP mentions the command line he wants eventually, no where do I see any flags or switches, and my answer is based on the assumption (which as you point out, might or might not be correct) that OP will not use that functionality. If he doesn't intend to, then `argparse` is overkill, if he does... there are already two other answers explaining how to use `argparse` correctly.